# using if else in Expression Queries c#

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

Assuming I have a linq expression query.

```
function a(DateTime timestamp){
from c in categories
***
if(dateTime is not null)
  //add where statement like c.UpdateDate < timestamp
***
select new Item
  {

  }
}
```

I would like to add the if-statement in the query when the timestamp that pass into the function is not null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build your query as you go.

```
var query = from c in categories select c;
if (dateTime is not null) {
    query = query.Where(c => c.UpdateDate < dateTime);
}
var results = query.Select(x => new Item { ... }).ToArray();
```

Another option is:

```
var query = from c in categories
            where (dateTime == null || c.UpdateDate < dateTime)
            select new Item { ... };
```

Note: this does create the equivalent condition in SQL. The first option does not.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this in one go?

Comment: What do you mean 'in one go'? This creates the most efficient query, but see my update for another option.

Comment: i think that is probably what I wanted, I mean in your first answer wouldn't it be something like selecting all items first and filtering out the datetime later, which will take more effort. I would like to know if you can explain since I am pretty new to c#.

Comment: It depends a bit on what the actual type of `categories` is. If it is an `IQueryable<T>`, then no, it doesnt retrieve all items. If it is an `IEnumerable<T>`, then yes, but that usually means it is in-memory anyway. Both are using deferred execution, so nothing is retrieved or iterated through until you materialize the resultset.